# Terraria Calamity mod - Permadeath in boss fight

Tags: terraria, mods

I was playing Terraria with Calamity mod in Death Mode and all my death worked like normal deaths on softcore, but when i died in my first boss figth it was a permadeath. I hadn't used Iron Heart.

Do all bosses permanently kill players while in Death Mode, even if Iron Heart isn't active?

Comment: What do you mean by "iron heart"?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Arqade! It would be helpful to provide additional context so others can understand what you're talking about. Suggestions include doing a brief description of the calamity mod, what death mode is, and what the iron heart does. Having this additional context will make it much more likely for someone to post a helpful answer.

Comment: @SkyPaul It's specific to the [calamity mod](https://calamitymod.gamepedia.com/Iron_Heart), which is why they mentioned it in the title.